# Can we increment and decrement the same metric if different labels come at runtime in Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus

Actually, I am using Gauge Metric in Prometheus to increment and decrement the value with the dynamic label "client_name". First, we initialize the metric with the below snippet -

```
clientMetric = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
    Name:          "Client",
    Help:          "Client operation performed",
    DynamicLabels: []string{"client_name"},
})
```

Then, we can use collector() type in Prometheus to set the updated value in clientMetric with below code snippet -

```
prometheus.Collector(func() {
//Get the client name from client DB. So "client" is just an entry.
val clientCount int
clientName := ""
if clientList != nil && len(*clientList) > 0 {
    for _, client := range *clientList {
        if client.ClientType == "IP" {
            clientCount = clientCount + 1
            clientName = client.ClientName
        }
    }

    if client != 0 {
        clientMetric.Set(float64(clientCount), clientName)
    } else {
        clientMetric.Set(float64(clientCount), clientName) 
    }
} else {
    clientMetric.Set(float64(clientCount), clientName)
}
})
```

If I check in the metrics port (http://localhost:9090/) then the data shows like:

```
Client{client_name="10.20.30.40", instance="50.40.30.20"}    1
Client{client_name="", instance="50.40.30.20"}               0
```

Here, the issue is getting two metrics but I want only one metric should come instead of a new metric being generated and the counter of 1 should be 0

Comment: That's how Prometheus metrics work, you'll get a value per unique combination of labels. When using the metric on a dashboard you can sum the values effectively "ignoring" the label(s) but generally it doesn't make sense to use labels like client id as the cardinality of the metric will be high and that will affect the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it possible to find another way to use the Prometheus type to achieve the above scenarios?